# Overloading + correctly in c++

Tags: c++, operators

I have created class which represents line `aX + bY = c`  and I wanted overload `+` operator to higher the line(return higher Line so I have done that below but compilator says `invalid use of this`

```
class Linia{
public:
    double a,b,c;
    Linia (double a, double b, double c){
        this->a = a;
        this->b = b;
        this->c = c;
    }
   friend Linia operator+ (double i){
   return new Linia(a, this->b, this->c + i/this->b);
}
};
```

I would like to return new `Linia` object which is has fields like shown above `i` is `int` i do not want to modify original object

Comment: That's basically C# with a `friend` thrown in.

Comment: `return new Linia(this->a, this->b, this->c + i/this->b)`

Comment: If operator+ is a friend, and not a member, there is no `this`. I'm not sure you *can* define a friend inline.

Comment: without this i get `invalid use of static member`

Comment: remove the `friend` than.

Comment: @millsj, You have an extra `new` there.

Comment: Okay, I need to understand what exactly you're trying to do with this class before I can effectively help you. (Besides, 'i' is a class, not an object, access the property if you want '+' to work.)

Comment: @StoryTeller, You can, but it remains that you obviously can't use `this`.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium, `i` is an object. However, there's no `operator/` in the sample.

Comment: @chris Argh, sorry, I completely mixed that up. Sorry...yes, it is an object, but not a 'primitive value', which could be added to another primitive value like that. THAT's what I meant to say. Sorry!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have some basic syntax issues.

- `this` is a pointer so you need to use `->` to dereference it.
- I assume you mean `this->c + i.c` instead of `this->c + i`
- You don't need to (and probably shouldn't) have the operator be a friend.
- Operators that return a new instance (like `operator+`) should return by value, not allocate on the heap.
- Operators generally take parameters as `const` references (since you shouldn't be modifying the operands).

I think you mean to have something like this:

```
class Linia{
public:
    double a,b,c;
    Linia (double a, double b, double c){
        this->a = a;
        this->b = b;
        this->c = c;
    }
    Linia operator+ (const Linia& i){
        return Linia(this->a, this->b, this->c + i.c / this->b);
    }
};
```

which you can clean up to be something like this:

```
class Linia{
public:
    double a,b,c;
    Linia (double a, double b, double c)
        : a(a), b(b), c(c)
    { }

    Linia operator+ (const Linia& i){
        return Linia(a, b, c + i.c / b);
    }
};
```

Comment: Why I cannot `return new Linia...`

Comment: @user1825608, Because this isn't C#. `new` returns a pointer, which isn't the same as an object.

Comment: @user1825608 The question is, why would you want to return `new Linea`? If you don't know the answer then chances are you really don't want to do it.

Comment: @user1825608 That is true C++ is necessary evil to me.

Comment: @user1825608 at least in C++ you don't have to type `new` all the time.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two problems in your code.  First, you've declared `operator+` to be a friend, so it is a free function, with no `this`.  Regretfully, from the code, I'm not able to figure out what you're trying to do (overload unary + or overload binary +), so it's difficult to say more.  Second, you're trying to return the results of `new`, which is a pointer, not an object type.  `operator+` should always return an object type, so you don't want the `new`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your `operator+` is a binary operator that takes two `Linia`s as input and returns a `Linea` having added coefficients, you may want to define a free function `operator+` overload, with proper const correctness of the input `Linia`s, like this:

```
Linia operator+(const Linia& lhs, const Linia& rhs)
{
    return Linia
    (
        lhs.a + rhs.a,
        lhs.b + rhs.b,
        lhs.c + rhs.c
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you declared it as a `friend`, your addition operator is not a member function, hence it must take two parameters, and has no access to `this`:

```
friend Linia operator+ (const Linia& lhs, const Linia& rhs)
{
  return Linia(lhs.a, lhs.b, lhs.c + rhs/lhs.b);
}
```

This follows the logic in your code but will only work if there is an operator `double operator/(const Linia& lhs, double)`. Something that intuitively would make sense would be

```
friend Linia operator+ (const Linia& lhs, const Linia& rhs)
{
  return Linia(lhs.a+rhs.a, lhs.b+rhs.b, lhs.c + rhs.c);
}
```

Finally, you could avoid the `friend` declaration completely and just declare the operator as a standard non-member function. It doesn't access any private or protected data, so it doesn't need to be a friend.

Comment: Since `a`, `b` and `c` are _public_ data members of `Linia`, I think `friend` is unnecessary.

Comment: @Mr.C64 it is unnecessary in this case, yes.